# Mariadb running but mysql.sock is on different directory

Tags: mariadb, migration

I was trying to move my database to a larger partition according to this [guide](https://www.tecmint.com/change-default-mysql-mariadb-data-directory-in-linux/).

My partition exists on `/mdb/mysql-data`, but when I edit the `my.cnf` file, it loads the old configuration on `my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf`.

Here's what I did:

> 1. I tried to comment the old ones but it won't run.
> 2. Run MariaDB with both configs: `mysql.sock` is on `/var/lib/mysql`
> 3. Moved my old directory by `mv /var/lib/mysql var/lib/mysql.bak`

Here's my current `.cnf`

[image: my.cnf]

My error after 3:

[image]
Why wont my socket generate on `/mdb/mysql-data/`?

Comment: Can you show the permission/ownership of `/mdb/mysql-data`? Does `/mdb` have chmod a+x permissions active? Does `journalctl -n 50 -u mariadb.service` show more detailed results of the the `mysql-prepare-db-dir` failure? Did you copy the data directory over to `/mdb/mysql-data` while it was shutdown?

Comment: Oh, this one's fixed, I just needed to run the following commands:

`$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -t mysql_db_t “/mdb/mysql-data(/.*)?”`
`$ sudo restorecon -R /mdb/mysql-data`

It was some SELinux stuff

Comment: Like was what is written in the guide you followed :-)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really read it thoroughly and missed it. It's a bad habit of mine. But I already made notes about how to do stuff properly.

Comment: Fix your habit of sloppiness quickly. Databases and the people that depend on them get rather unpleasant when simple sloppy mistakes cause outages for hours/days.

Comment: No worries, this was 4 months ago, I've been improving myself since then :)